# dompdf error Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

My case is a little bit more complicated than the others answered before. with the same code the results are different.

**WORKING CENARIO - 1st step**

Go to http://renamchristofoletti.com/en/works/covers/

Click on Thumbnails, and ADD TILL 4 images.

Click on Download, and than, Download Portfolio.

PDF was generated as expected. =)

**ERROR CENARIO - 2nd step**

Do the same thing as above, but now, add more than 6 images in the Thumbnails.

PDF get a "Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent error"

Doesn't matter with image are you selecting, same thing happens.

**DOMPDF CODE**

```
ob_clean();
echo '<html><body>...'; // above html and css goes here

$images2 = str_replace(' ', "", $_COOKIE['rc_folio']);
$images = explode(',', $images2);
$images = array_filter($images);

foreach ( $images as $image ) {
    $img_id = get_image_id($image);

    $imglocal = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $img_id );

        $img_abs_path = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/' . $imglocal['file'];
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_abs_path);
        if ($width > $height) {
            // Landscape
            echo '<div style="page-break-after: always; text-align: center;"><div class="content-line"></div><div class="content-line-2"></div><img src="' . $img_abs_path . '" style="width: 80%; max-width: 80%; height: auto; margin-top: 250px;" /></div>'; 
        } else {
            // Portrait or Square
            echo '<div style="page-break-after: always; text-align: center;"><div class="content-line"></div><div class="content-line-2"></div><img src="' . $img_abs_path . '" style="width: auto; height: 60%; max-height: 60%; margin-top: 180px;" /></div>';
        }
}
echo '</body></html>';

$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_get_clean();

$pdf_path = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/themes/moqueca/dompdf-master/dompdf_config.inc.php';
require_once( $pdf_path );

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper('letter', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("renam_christofoletti_customfolio.pdf");
exit();
```

Please can anyone clarify my mind about this? I've tried many other solutions, but nothing seens to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why using the `ob_clean` etc. I don't think it is a recommended way. Can you convert all your `echo` to `$html .= '` and finally use that? Let me know if you still get the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be running up against a limit in the output buffer size. You can check to see if there's a size limit by checking the value of the [`output_buffering`](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) configuration parameter:

```
echo ini_get('output_buffering');
```

If this is the case you can either modify the buffer size:

```
ini_set('output_buffering', true); // no limit
ini_set('output_buffering', 12288); // 12KB limit
```

or follow the instructions in Dharam's comment to your question and push the content into a variable directly rather than relying on output buffering:

```
$html = '<html><body>...'; // above html and css goes here

$images2 = str_replace(' ', "", $_COOKIE['rc_folio']);
$images = explode(',', $images2);
$images = array_filter($images);

foreach ( $images as $image ) {
    $img_id = get_image_id($image);

    $imglocal = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $img_id );

        $img_abs_path = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/' . $imglocal['file'];
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_abs_path);
        if ($width > $height) {
            // Landscape
            $html .= '<div style="page-break-after: always; text-align: center;"><div class="content-line"></div><div class="content-line-2"></div><img src="' . $img_abs_path . '" style="width: 80%; max-width: 80%; height: auto; margin-top: 250px;" /></div>'; 
        } else {
            // Portrait or Square
            $html .= '<div style="page-break-after: always; text-align: center;"><div class="content-line"></div><div class="content-line-2"></div><img src="' . $img_abs_path . '" style="width: auto; height: 60%; max-height: 60%; margin-top: 180px;" /></div>';
        }
}
$html .= '</body></html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Case solved. I just changed echo for html .= and everything works perfect.

Thanks.